# sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "7nbtkq"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into my SQL database however, I am receiving the following error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "7nbtkq".

Note, the value 7nbtkq is a public key of one of the data that I am trying to update.

I have looked at several other solutions but they are either different scenarios that don't apply to mine or their solutions haven't worked for me.

```
sql = """UPDATE parent_reply SET parent_id = '{}', comment_id = '{}', parent = '{}', comment = '{}', subreddit = {}, unix = {}, score = {} WHERE parent_id ={};""".format(parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit, int(time), score, parentid)
c.execute(sql)
```

I am expecting my SQL database to be updated with these new values on the according record.

Comment: `SET parent_id = '{}' ... WHERE parent_id ={}` looks like one of placeholders is wrong. Shouldn't both be surrounded by quotes?

Comment: BTW, why update parent_id with the value it currently has?

Comment: @Serg I am really just trying to update those data like comment id and etc. Do you think I should remove the `parent_id = '{}'` in ` `SET parent_id = '{}' . . . WHERE parent_id = '{}'` because it has to be anyway due to the WHEN?

Comment: I see no reason to have  `parent_id = '{}'` in `SET` clause.

Comment: @Serg Okay, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should give `''` to each value except `int`:

```
sql = """UPDATE parent_reply SET parent_id = '{}', comment_id = '{}', parent = '{}', comment = '{}', subreddit = '{}', unix = {}, score = '{}' WHERE parent_id ='{}'""".format(parentid, commentid, parent, comment, subreddit, int(time), score, parentid)
```